# Maintaining original object as constant

Tags: javascript, object

I have assigned some data to the one object and I want that object in future as it was like the first time. Whenever I do changes for the parent object it is getting reflected in the child object too. How can I solve this? Please give all possible answer for the object, arrays, maps also.

```
var parentObject = someData;
const childObj = Object.assign({}, parentObject);
```

I want to change only parent object and I want to keep child object as constant to use in the future.

Comment: You can use `object.freeze` to prevent it's properties being changed.

Comment: Can you give an example of this?

Comment: Deep copy it with json stringify/parse, you most likely not after freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method to check weather an Object is frozen or not. Here is an example where I merged parent and child object and then freeze the child object. 
Again If call the `mergeObject()` to merge the parent and child, nothing is merged. Since we freeze the child object after first merge.

```js
/**
 * Merge two object using Object.assign()
 * @param parentObj
 * @param childObj
 * @returns {ReadonlyArray<any>} returns frozen object
 */
function mergeObject(parentObj, childObj) {
   return Object.isFrozen(childObj) ? childObj : Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, parentObj))
}

// Before freezing
var parentObject = {a: 4};
var childObj = mergeObject(parentObject, {});
console.log(childObj); // {a: 4}

// After freezing
parentObject.b = 6;
childObj = mergeObject(parentObject, childObj);
console.log(childObj); // {a: 4}, didn't merge {b: 6}
```